# Как можно получить нативным JS полную ширину элемента с учетом border, margin, padding?

Tags: javascript

Как можно получить нативным JS полную ширину элемента с учетом border, margin, padding, если эти свойства не заданы через JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так

```js
var element = document.getElementById("elem");
var marginLeft = parseInt(getComputedStyle(element, true).marginLeft);
var marginRight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(element, true).marginRight);
console.log(element.offsetWidth + marginLeft + marginRight)
```

```css
#elem {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: А должно было быть 362

Comment: А разве margin учитывается? 332 полная ширина блока

Comment: не работает, scrollWidth учитывает только  `padding`, а `clientWidth` -  `padding` и `border`

Comment: `clientWidth` не учитывает border) `offsetWidth` учитывает)

Comment: Вы прочитали вопрос?

Comment: @Puvvl, ошибся)

Comment: Дописал, теперь `margin` учитывается.

Answer (score 3):

Берем `offsetWidth` который включает в себя `padding` и `border`.

А для `margin`. используем [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
var element = document.getElementById('offsetWidth');

var style = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
 
var width = element.offsetWidth;

var margin = parseFloat(style.marginLeft) + parseFloat(style.marginRight);


var allWidth = width + margin;

console.log(allWidth);
```

```css
#offsetWidth{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="offsetWidth"></div>
```

Comment: Можно еще проще: var margin = parseFloat(style.margin)*2;